# C# handling callback result

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, icallbackeventhandler

e
I am a little struggling with the following conditions. I have implemented ICallBackEventHandler in my web pages, everything runs smooth except that returning value from the back-end is not readable for the javascript function. In the console the post shows up the correct returning value, but the argument of the function is always empty.

```
public partial class Intro : System.Web.UI.Page, System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
{
private string eventType = String.Empty;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //ICallBack event handler
        ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
        string cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "HandleResult", "");

        string cbScript = "function RaiseEvent(arg){" + cbReference + ";}";
        cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RaiseEvent", cbScript, true);
        //End of ICallBack event handler
    }


 }

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        eventType = eventArgument;
    }
    public string GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return "simple";
    }
```

And then in the front-end I have the following scenario: I trigger the event on button click using this : `RaiseEvent("start")` and I am handling the result with the this function :

```
function HandleResult(arg) {
            alert(arg); // HERE THE ARGUMENT IS ALWAYS NULL OR EMPTY !!!
        }
```

Please help me find out why this is not running properly and why I cannot access the value of the returned argument. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by not using the Page.IsPostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
    //ICallBack event handler
    ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
    string cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "HandleResult", "");

    string cbScript = "function RaiseEvent(arg){" + cbReference + ";}";
    cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RaiseEvent", cbScript, true);
    //End of ICallBack event handler
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is not the issue.